# problemas al hacer deploy a una webapp vue-express-mongodb en Heroku

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, mongodb, express, heroku

esta es la primera vez que subo un proyecto a Heroku. He creado una pequeña aplicacion web usando ExpressJS - MongoDB - VueJS, la cual funciona de forma perfecta en local. Al intentar subirla a Heroku utilizando el metodo de Heroku - Github (no estoy usando Heroku-cli), me salta el siguiente error casi al final del proceso:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-eslint'
Require stack:
- /tmp/build_a092ddb4/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /tmp/build_a092ddb4/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at idToPlugin (/tmp/build_a092ddb4/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:145:14)
at /tmp/build_a092ddb4/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:184:20
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Service.resolvePlugins (/tmp/build_a092ddb4/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:170:10)
at new Service (/tmp/build_a092ddb4/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:32:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_a092ddb4/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js:15:17) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'/tmp/build_a092ddb4/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js',
'/tmp/build_a092ddb4/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js'
]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BrlqB/_logs/2022-02-18T04_31_38_608Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Food-Spending@1.0.0 build: `npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Food-Spending@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BrlqB/_logs/2022-02-18T04_31_38_623Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
   
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/
   
   Love,
   Heroku
   
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed
```

alguien sabe por qué me esta fallando el proceso justamente con module '@vue/cli-plugin-eslint' ?
Ya anteriormente me habia estado dando errores en el proceso de deploy con otras dependencias relacionadas con @vue/cli-service, pero logré solucionarlos... sin embargo a este error no le he podido encontrar solución.

este es el codigo del archivo package.json del lado de Vuejs:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
     "node": "12.x"
   },
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
       "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
       "build": "vue-cli-service build",
       "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
   },
  "dependencies": {
      "axios": "^0.25.0",
      "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
      "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
      "core-js": "^3.6.5",
      "vue": "^2.6.14",
      "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
      "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
      "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
      "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
      "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
      "eslint": "^6.7.2",
      "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
      "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
     "root": true,
     "env": {
       "node": true
     },
  "extends": [
     "plugin:vue/essential",
     "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
   },
   "rules": {}
  },
 "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente, luego de buscar intensamente en internet, conseguí algunos tips que me ayudaron a resolver el problema. Lo que hice fue:

Primero, Eliminé completamente el proyecto Vue que habia creado en la parte del frontend (el backend no lo toqué) y cree uno nuevo pero esta vez sin seleccionar la opción eslint/formatted durante la instalación.
Luego, edité los archivos package.json y package-lock.json, especificamente en "dependencies" he agregado:

```
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
```

es decir, el cambio en package.json fue:

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.25.0",
  "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
  "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "vue": "^2.6.14",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
},
```

Con estos cambios, mi aplicación finalmente se pudo desplegar y esta funcionando perfectamente en producción.
No estoy segura si esta es la mejor solución ó si existen otras mejores, pero investigaré sobre ello.